# Why is Power BI HTTP Response stating I've hit maximum number of Dataflow Refreshes?

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, powerbi, power-automate

I've created a Power Automate connector which allows a user to create an SQL triggered refresh sequence which cascades all the way through the Dataflow refresh to the Dataset refresh thus eliminating the need for schedules. It seemed to work well when testing yesterday and then I hit the 8th refresh and it started failing. However, when I looked at it today, it seems the first 2 refreshes failed today and I am still getting this error although it only fired twice today. I have set up on Power BI 7 refreshes but it hasn't hit all of them yet in order to return this message. I tried to switch the refresh off on the dataflow but still to no avail. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "DailyDataflowRefreshLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Skipping dataflow refresh as number of auto refreshes in last 24 hours (8) exceeded allowed limit 8"
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I've just tried the same flow on a new Power BI workspace for the first time and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely hit 8 refresh limit in 24 hours. you will have to wait complete 24 hours to perform next set of refresh.

Short answer to lift this limitation, you may have to buy a premium license(48 times per day)

[Blog stating the same](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Data-Refresh-API-vs-Scheduled-refresh/td-p/214943)

[Blog from PowerBI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/)

Comment: I waited for about 5 hours and disabled the auto-refresh on the reports and seems to have worked. After more reading it seems I had to wait until there were less than 8 hits within the last 24 hours. So 24 hours after the time of the previous 7th refresh it seems I could kick it back in. The DB I'm pulling from will trigger 6 times a day so that should be sorted now